# Generate openvpn-client keys based on asuswrt ca

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

#### Question

How can I authenticate a client on my openvpn-server (running asuswrt) with just a certificate?

---

> Crosspost from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032124/generate-openvpn-client-keys-based-on-asuswrt-ca (no comments, no answers in 7 days)

#### More Info

Enabling and configuring the built in openvpn-server is really easy. By default I can export a `client.ovpn` file and set new users and passwords, which lets me connect to the routers vpn-network just fine.

[image: openvpn-server settings]

The marked setting `Username / Password Auth. Only` was set to YES previously.

[image]

The router has its own CA I guess (presumably set up with with `easy-rsa` and some init scripts from asus) and all the CA params are available to me (as seen in the picture above). Now, how do I generate client certificates and set the server to allow authentication with only the client certificate?
The username / pass option would equal to two factor auth which only adds more security but wouldn't be irresponsible to not use (IMHO).
I would like to use this in a small hobby project to connect all the team members.

#### Client config

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote xxx.XXX.xxx.XXX 443
float
comp-lzo adaptive
keepalive 15 60
ns-cert-type server
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
......
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

#### Server config (located in /etc/openvpn/server1/config.ovpn)

```
# Automatically generated configuration
daemon
server-bridge
push "route 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"
proto udp
port 443
dev tap21
comp-lzo adaptive
keepalive 15 60
verb 3
duplicate-cn
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
ca ca.crt
dh dh.pem
cert server.crt
key server.key
status-version 2
status status
```

Comment: Okay an update in this matter: I used to easy-rsa scripts on my linux box to create an all new CA with all the certificates. They verify all fine versus the `openssl verify` command. With password I can auth on the server and initiate a connection. When I delete the line `auth-user-pass` from the client config file, I get this error: `UDPv4 link local: [undef]`.

Comment: Suggestion: the lines starting with `plugin ..` and `duplicate-cn` should be removed from the server config.
The files modified in `/etc/openvpn/server1` get reset on a vpnserver-restart (toggled via the button in the UI, can't find service restart command for openvpn). There is a copy of the filesystem in `/tmp`. No idea why, should look into embeded stuff.

Comment: restart commands are  
`service stop_vpnserver1` and  
`service start_vpnserver1`